# How do I use custom-operators in Doctrine DQL?

Tags: doctrine-orm, postgis, dql

I am trying to use PostGIS functions in my queries. I am using [`jsor/doctrine-postgis`](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis) package to add relevant functionality to Doctrine. I am not exactly sure if I have configured it incorrectly or if I am doing something wrong.

For example:

```
->where('ST_Intersects(st.coords,ST_MakeEnvelope(-1,-1,1,1,4326))')
```

However this does not work because syntax checker wants a comparison operator. I get the following error:

> Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string

I managed to avoid this error by checking true/false. While this is undesirable, it works.

->where('ST_Intersects(st.coords,ST_MakeEnvelope(-1,-1,1,1,4326))=true')

But I want to use the `&&` operator. I am not sure exactly how can I manage that? What I mean is something like this:

```
->where('st.coords && ST_MakeEnvelope(-1,-1,1,1,4326))')
```

But this returns an error:

> Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got '&'

Am I doing something wrong? This feels over-complicated for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis/issues/27). There is nothing you can do. From jsor, the author

> AFAICT, implementing custom operators isn't possible with Doctrine :( I don't think i can do much here. The only solution i'm aware of is using [Doctrine's Native SQL feature](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html). Closing for now. Feel free to reopen if you have further questions/ideas.

So your only option is [`->createNativeQuery`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) if you want to make use of a GIST index, [or `geometry_overlaps` if you don't care.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191669/2639)

Comment: Yes, I actually found the same issue. But wanted to be 100% sure that it does not have a workaround.

I tried it already and it feels like I am cursed :) I use geography type so geometry_overlaps didn't work but geography_overlaps works. It is silly because && automatically selects correct function. Makes me wonder why they wouldn't have a normal function for this operation..
I would use native query, but it feels wrong to install a package to support postgis then write query in native query builder... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add " = true" at end of where:

```
     /**
     * @param string $bbox
     * @param int|null $limit
     * @return MyEntity[]
     */
    public function findByCoordinatesBoundingBox(string $bbox, int $limit = null): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('n')
            ->where("ST_Intersects(n.coordinates, ST_MakeEnvelope({$bbox})) = true")
            ->orderBy('n.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
            ;
    }
```