# Custom filter with nativeQuery

Tags: doctrine-orm, postgis, api-platform.com

I want to perform a custom filter to retrieve an area inside a boundingBox via a custom filter

basic query will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM public.area
where coord  
    @ ST_MakeEnvelope (
        -71, 48, 
        -72, 49)
```

In [filterProperty](https://github.com/leesiongchan/api-platform-core/blob/master/src/Bridge/Doctrine/Orm/Filter/AbstractFilter.php#L78) method we have access only to the `queryBuilder` (due to the logic of `apiplatform`)

that we look something like this:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->andWhere('o.coord @ ST_MakeEnvelope(:min_x, :min_y, :max_x, :max_y))')
```

but doctrine parser throw an error because of the unknown operator (see [How do I use custom-operators in Doctrine DQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47476822/how-do-i-use-custom-operators-in-doctrine-dql))

so my only option is to perform a `nativeQuery` but with the logic of ApiPlatform I don't know how to achieve that, im not sure if it's even possible without breaking the logic of ApiPlatform filter

package used for postGIS is https://github.com/jsor/doctrine-postgis

Comment: To resolve my issue, I've make a custom data collection provider https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-collection-data-provider  and write a native query and implement my own Filter and Paginator to achieve the same results as a classic endpoint in api platform